# django queryset API

Tags: python, django

Suppose i have :

models.py:

```
class Books(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    price = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

and in `manage.py shell` :

```
# hits the database
>>> book_one = Books.objects.get(id = 1)
# hits the database 
>>> foo = book_one.title
u'Foo book'
```

assuming on the code above, if i type `book_one.author` we're gonna hit the database again.

By using `select_related()` if i type `book_one.title` or `book_one.author` or `book_one.price` we're not gonna hit the database again, only when we instance it.

If i type `books = Books.objects.all()` in `manage.py shell` and let's say i want to store its specific value (let's say i only want to store `title` and `author` field) in an empty list using `for` loop like :

```
empty_list = []
for book in books:
    empty_list.append([book.title, book.author])
# only 1 data, so we're gonna loop only once
```

So the question is : based on that loop above, how many times we're gonna hit the database?   Is it 2 times because we pass `book.title` and `book.author` or only once

Comment: you will not hit the database again for book_one.title or book_one.author

Comment: really? because the docs says it's gonna hit the database again https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: what i meant was about your first statement..
# hits the database
>>> book_one = Books.objects.get(id = 1)
# hits the database -- [no it will not ]
>>> book_one.title
u'Foo book'

Comment: select_related is for related objects (foreign keys)

Answer (score 2):

> assuming on the code above, if i type `book_one.author` we're gonna hit the database again.

Incorrect. All simple fields in a model are pulled from the database unless `.defer()` or `.only()` are used.

> By using `select_related()` if i type `book_one.title` or `book_one.author` or `book_one.price` we're not gonna hit the database again, only when we instance it.

`select_related()` only affects related fields, e.g. `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField`, etc.

> based on that loop above, how many times we're gonna hit the database?

Once. But consider using `.values_list('title', 'author')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class

```
class Books(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    price = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

Now,

```
>>> book_one = Books.objects.get(id = 1) # hits the database
>>> foo = book_one.title # does not hit the database
```

if at all `title` was a foreign key to another table then, `foo = book_one.title` would have hit the database and using `select_related` would have saved you this database hit

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is not correct. Querysets [are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), and are only executed when evaluated.

```
f = Books.objects.get(pk=1) # one hit
f.title # no hit
f.price # no hit
```